# Account Team member clone LWC component

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have created a LWC component which should be an exact replica of the Account team member, i am not able to figure it out for the "View All" logic needs to be given there as when I am clicking view all for any account its is taking me to only a single specific account team member related page

Js script:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from "lwc";
import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";
import getSingleAccount from "@salesforce/apex/AccountController.getSingleAccount";
export default class clientTeam extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
  @wire(getSingleAccount) account;
  navigateToRelatedList() {
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
      type: "standard__recordRelationshipPage",
      attributes: {
        recordId: this.account.data.Id,
        objectApiName: "Account",
        relationshipApiName: "AccountTeamMembers",
        actionName: "view"
      },
      state: {
        filterName: "related"
      }
    });
  }
}
```

html

```
<template>
    <lightning-card  title="Hello">
        <lightning-button label="New" slot="actions"></lightning-button>
        <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">Card Body (custom component)</p>
        <lightning-button variant="brand" label='view all' title='view all' onclick={navigateToRelatedList}></lightning-button>
    </lightning-card>
</template>


apex class controller:-
public with sharing class AccountController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Account> getAccountList() {
        return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED LIMIT 10];
    }
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Account getSingleAccount() {
        return [
            SELECT Id
            FROM Account
            WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
         
            LIMIT 1
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "should be an exact replica of the Account team member"?  Please [edit] your post to include details on what you are trying to build.

Comment: So every Salesforce org has a standard account team member related card on the account page layout, i have to create the exact custom LWC component of it.